# Python sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I've listed all over SO but didn't find the correct answer for my situation. I found this code to sort a dictionary:

```
min_key = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
```

And it does the sorting right, but now I need to run this code
for

```
{ '10.8.68.192': 9, '10.8.69.42': 9}
```

and for

```
{ '10.8.69.42': 9, '10.8.68.192': 9 }
```

and I need it return '10.8.68.192' no matter in what order are they(if values are same sort by key). Any ideas ?

Comment: y u want to sort, if you want specific ip???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all use `min()` here not `sorted()`* if you want the smallest key that satisfies your condition, and you can use a tuple to specify multiple arguments for comparison.

```
>>> d = { '10.8.68.192': 9, '10.8.69.42': 9}
>>> min(d, key=lambda x: (d[x], map(int, x.split('.'))))
'10.8.68.192'
#or
>>> import socket
>>> min(d, key=lambda x: (d[x], socket.inet_aton(x)))
'10.8.68.192'
```

---

*
<sub>(`min()` takes `O(N)` time and `O(1)` memory, on the other hand `sorted()` will take `O(NlogN)` time and will create an unnecessary list in memory).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can sort on a tuple, like `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))`.

Note that using an IP address string for sorting will order lexicographically, which places e.g. `12.0.0.10` before `127.0.0.2`. `socket.inet_aton(ip)` will convert an IPv4 address to a 32-bit integer which fixes this problem.

Comment: This will not work as you're comparing numbers in string lexicographically.

Comment: **(if values are same sort by key).**

Comment: While you are correct about lexicographic ordering, I would argue that the proper way to compare IPv4 addresses is not to split them into a tuple on the decimal places, but to convert entirely to/from an integer.

Answer (score -1):

for this i will use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_dict = { '10.8.69.42': 9, '10.8.68.192': 9 }
>>> re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.192'," ".join(my_dict.keys()))
['10.8.68.192']
```

Comment: What makes you think that he always wants the IP that ends in 192? He wants the _lowest_ IP.